# Find the integral values for which $\left(\pi(x+y)\right)^2=4\pi(x)\pi(y)$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function. The problem is,

> Find all integral values of $x,y$ such that,
>
> $$\left(\pi(x+y)\right)^2=4\pi(x)\pi(y)$$

I have no idea as to where to begin with. I think that probably there will be inequality after some sufficiently large $x$ and $y$ but I can't prove that.

In fact, it appears that for all sufficiently large $x$ and $y$ we will have $4\pi(x)\pi(y)>(\pi(x+y))^2$ but I can't find the lower bound.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should define the functions you use in your questions, even because this is not tagged "prime numbers" or stuff like that.

Comment: I did it for you this time, see if that's OK or you want to change something.

Comment: We know that $c_1\cdot \frac{x}{\ln x}<\pi(x)<c_2\cdot \frac{x}{\ln x}$ for some $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{R}$ closely to $1$.  
Therefore, $(\pi(x+y))^2>c_1^2\frac{(x+y)^2}{(\ln (x+y))^2}$ and $\pi(x)\cdot \pi(y)<c_2^2\frac{x}{\ln x}\cdot \frac{y}{\ln y}$  
If your equation holds true then we must have $$c_1^2\frac{(x+y)^2}{(\ln (x+y))^2}<c_2^2\frac{x}{\ln x}\cdot \frac{y}{\ln y}$$ which can hold only for some finite amount of numbers if we assume $x\leq y$.Just a little help.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: So are you saying that $(\pi(x+y))^2\ge4\pi(x)\pi(y)$ for all sufficiently large $\min(x,y)$?

Comment: @user170039 yes If I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every prime $p$ we have
$$
\pi(p+k) = \pi(p + k + \ell),
$$
where both $k$ and $\ell$ are positive, and $k + \ell < n_p$, and $n_p$ is defined as
$$
\pi(p) + 1 = \pi(p+n_p) = \pi(p')
$$

We look for solutions
$$
\pi^2(p + k + \ell) = 4 \pi(p + k) \pi(\ell),
$$

such that
$$
\pi(p + k + \ell) = \pi(p + k) = 4 \pi(\ell)
$$

which is easier to solve.

Case $\ell = 2$.
$$
\ell=2 \Rightarrow \pi(\ell) = 1 : \pi(p) = 4 \Rightarrow p = 7,
n_7 = 4, \ell < 4.
$$
So these solutions are
$$
(x,y) \in \big\{ (2,7), (2,8), (7,2), (8,2) \big\}.
$$

Case $\ell = 3$.
$$
\ell=3 \Rightarrow \pi(\ell) = 2 : \pi(p) = 8 \Rightarrow p = 19,
n_19 = 4, \ell < 4.
$$
So these solutions are
$$
(x,y) \in \big\{ (3,19), (19,3) \big\}.
$$

Higher solutions do not seem to appear, as $\pi(p)$ grows faster then $n_p$...

Comment: Can you tell me what is $p'$?

Comment: The next prime... It is just a notation...

Consider $p=5$, then $p'=7$...

Comment: By the way, you have solved the case when $\pi(p+k+l)=\pi(p+k)=4\pi(l)$. How can we resolve the case where $\pi(p+k+l)=2\pi(p+k)=2\pi(l)$? Does that mean that for all sufficiently large $x$ and $y$ we will have $(\pi(x+y))^2<4\pi(x)\pi(y)$?

Comment: Then $p+k$ and $\ell$ share the same starting prime.

Comment: What about the inequality $(\pi(x+y))^2<4\pi(x)\pi(y)$? Seems probable right?

Comment: I need to check it. But it seem right...