# A question on the inequality $\bigl(\pi(x+y)\bigr)^2<4\pi(x)\pi(y)$

Tags: number-theory

From the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096548/find-the-integral-values-for-which-left-pixy-right2-4-pix-piy) it seems highly probable that
the following problem can be proved,

> Show that for all sufficiently large $\min(x,y)$ we will have, $$\bigl(\pi(x+y)\bigr)^2<4\pi(x)\pi(y)$$Find the optimal lower bound of $\min(x,y)$ so that the above inequality holds. Here $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes less than or equal to $x$.

However, the only thing that I have found till now is that when $x=y$, the inequality trivially holds.

Note also that we have, $\bigl(\pi(x+y)\bigr)^2<4\bigl(\pi(x)\bigr)^2$ for all $x\ge 3$ and $x\ge y$.

Can anyone suggest any method of showing it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly when you write on the last line $(\pi(x+y))^2<4(\pi(x))^2$ for all $x\geq 3$, but this is certainly not true. Take $x=3$ and $y\geq4$. Then we have $16\leq\pi^2(x+y)<16$, which is obviously false.

Comment: By the Prime Number Theorem, for every constant $C>1$, if $x$ and $y$ are large enough, then $\pi(x+y)<C(x+y)/\log(x+y)$ and $\pi(x)>(1/C)x/\log x$. That should give you a good start.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I have already applied the inequalities but I can't conclude anything from that. Maybe we need some stronger bounds on the function $\pi(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this not false? Assume contrariwise that there exists a lower bound $C$ such that the claim holds for all $x,y\ge C$. Let $y=C$. There are infinitely many prime gaps of length $C$, say the interval $[k!+2,k!+C+2]$ for any $k>C+2$. So if $x$ is the lower end of such an interval, we have $\pi(x+y)=\pi(x)$.

In that case your claim reads
$$
\pi(x)^2<4\pi(x)\pi(C),
$$
or, equivalently
$$
\pi(x)<4\pi(C).
$$
Because here $C$ is fixed, and $x$ can be made as large as we wish, this is absurd.

Comment: Here $x$ is ridiculously large in comparison to $y$, so you probably need to rephrase the conjecture in such a way that $x$ and $y$ are at least loosely tied to each other.